# How to enforce that an inner button takes the full height of the enclosing div element

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and I am trying to build a minimalistic navbar. I want the head item to take up the full height of the outer (yellow-ish) container but I am failing to accomplish that. Which CSS command enables this?

I tried to height: auto and setting margins to 0 but the button wouldn't take-up the space above/below it.

My html:

```
<div className="navbar">
        <div className="dropdown">
          <button className="dropdown-head">Head item 1</button>
          <div className="dropdown-items">
            <a href="#">Sub item 1-1</a>
            <a href="#">Sub item 1-2</a>
            <a href="#">Sub item 1-3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="dropdown">
          <button className="dropdown-head">Head item 2</button>
          <div className="dropdown-items">
            <a href="#">Sub item 2-1</a>
            <a href="#">Sub item 2-2</a>
            <a href="#">Sub item 2-3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: khaki;
}

/* .dropdown {
  background-color: white;
} */

.dropdown-head {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  min-width: 160px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown-items {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* z-index: 1; */
}

.dropdown-items a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-items {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-head {
  background-color: rgb(238, 3, 199);
}

.dropdown-items a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(155, 155, 155);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div className="navbar">
        <div className="dropdown">
          <button className="dropdown-head">Head item 1</button>
          <div className="dropdown-items">
            <a href="#">Sub item 1-1</a>
            <a href="#">Sub item 1-2</a>
            <a href="#">Sub item 1-3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="dropdown">
          <button className="dropdown-head">Head item 2</button>
          <div className="dropdown-items">
            <a href="#">Sub item 2-1</a>
            <a href="#">Sub item 2-2</a>
            <a href="#">Sub item 2-3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You have two dropdowns inside the navbar, is this intentional? They seem to take up the height of the navbar since they are displayed on top of each other.

Comment: Yes, I want to have multiple top-level items in the navbar such as "home", "contact us", "imprint" - these top-level items will have sub-dropdowns.